# removeItemByKey not working in product collection - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection, magento-2.1.7

I have a product collection (`\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection`), I try to remove some of the item from the collection by using below code.

```
foreach ($collection->getItems() as $key => $d)
{
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($d['entity_id']);
    if(!$product->getIsSalable())
    {
        var_dump($d['entity_id']);
        $collection->removeItemByKey($key);
    }
}
var_dump($collection->getData());die();
```

but collection object still has that value. please help us to remove the item from the collection.

Comment: try `$collection->removeItemByKey($d->getId());`

Comment: it doesn't work @Priyank still removed item present in the collection data

Comment: I can confirm @Priyank's  answer is not working. Did you finally find a solution?

Comment: up to my mind, I used array unset() function to remove element from an array.